# I/O errors on Linux LVM

Tags: linux, lvm, fsck

I have a CentOS 6 box with LVM setup and one of the PVs is a USB disk (I know).  One of them is getting the error:

```
Oct 30 10:57:07 alpha01 kernel: lost page write due to I/O error on dm-3
Oct 30 10:57:07 alpha01 kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 4
```

Which is causing problems with all of the LVs on it.  pvs shows the PV as unknown device.  I can ls to the logical volumes and they show up in lvdisplay, but first I get a bunch of IO errors.  I made sure the cables are secure between the USB drive.  What should I do to get this back up and running for the meanwhile?  Should I unmount each LV and run an fsck.ext4 on each one like `fsck.ext4 -y /dev/vg1/lv_logvolname` ?

Comment: In addition to fsck, if the external drive is SMART capable, checking the drive status/health and running the drive self tests may be useful.  Backing up all the data may also be important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually don't go the route of running an `fsck` and assume the disk is failing or has bad sectors. I definitely wouldn't run the `fsck` using the `-y`, since this will give `fsck` to attempt to start moving blocks which may exacerbate the problem.

Instead I'll run a tool such as [Spinrite (Commercial)](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) or [HDAT2 (freeware)](http://www.hdat2.com/) on the disk to do the analysis & potential repair.

#### What else?

See my other answers to these questions for additional methods:

- [fsck -cc /dev/sdb1 gives this result. Is everything okay>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93714/fsck-cc-dev-sdb1-gives-this-result-is-everything-okay/93732#93732)
- [Detect damaged audio CD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82283/detect-damaged-audio-cd)

The 2nd link provides details about another tool, [`safecopy`](http://safecopy.sourceforge.net/) for attempting to recover data from a failed/failing drive. It doesn't attempt to do any repairing of hte HDD.

Comment: Is there a linux spinrite that can be run from a normal runlevel 3 without a boot cd, and simply analyze specific filesystems?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - no you have to reboot the system to do this analysis. I typically pull the drive out of the system and run it standalone. Another tool that's been used to do this is `badblocks`.